# I have a mathematical problem that is beyond my skill level. Can someone please help?

Tags: geometry

My problem is that i do not have the necessary skills to calculate the angle at which the spring ought to be mounted, so that when the force is applied to the belt, the force that is also applied to the spring is parallel to the spring, to eliminate binding. The first drawing gives all measurements, the second illustrates my problem.

[image: first image]

[image: second image]

Sorry my drawings are so crude. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let Wheel $A$(diameter: $\frac{3}{8}$), Wheel $B$(diameter $\frac{5}{4}$), Wheel $C$(diameter: $\frac{7}{8}$). We make trianle $ABC$.

$BC$ = $\frac{31}{8}$,  height of triangle $\frac{39}{16}$. Draw the line from the center of $A$ to $BC$ and intersects it at $D$ (So, $AD$ as the height ). $BD$ = $\frac{21}{8}$,  $CD$ = $\frac{5}{4}$. Then we calculate,  $\angle B$: $\arctan(\frac{BD}{AD})$ $=$ $\arctan$($\frac{\frac{39}{16}}{\frac{21}{8}}$), which is $42.88$. angle $\angle C$: $arctan$($\frac{BD}{DC}$) $=$ $arctan$($\frac{\frac{39}{16}}{\frac{5}{4}}$), which is 62.85. 
So, we get $\angle A$ = $180-(62.85 + 42.88)$. If the force is applied like the photo, the spring bisects the $\angle A$. The angle is approximately 37.135?